# hoe generate license after install sysam license server

Tags: sybase-ase15

Dears, while I am installing sybase ase 15.7, I install sysam license server, but I don't know now how to generate license (EE:enterprise)
by default, Sysam generates a license file in licenses directory but this license is developer edition,

anyone know about this point.
please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get to the Sybase (now SAP) web site, log in with your customer ID and geneate the license key. This is possible only when you have actually purchased the ASE Enterprise Edition. If you (or your company) did, but you don't know how to log in, contact SAP support to help you forward.